# Difficulty when using \ifthenelse{\equal{ }} to determine tilde (~) status

Tags: conditionals, xstring

I'm having to determine whether the tilde (~) character exists at the end of a string, but I am seeing differing results depending on the macro, e.g:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifendSwith}[2][~]{%
 \IfEndWith{#2}{#1}{true}{false}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\trimend}[1]{%
  \trim@post@space{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifendSwith{\textasciitilde }{\trimend{. -string~}} \par
\ifendSwith{\textasciitilde{} }{\trimend{. -string~}} \par
\ifendSwith{$\sim$}{\trimend{. -string~}} \par
\ifendSwith{\~{}}{\trimend{. -string~}} \par
\ifendSwith{~}{\trimend{. -string~}} \par
\ifendSwith{\trimend{. -string~}} \par

% How test value of a command with `\ifthenelse` and `\equal`?
\ifthenelse{\equal{\ifendSwith{ -string~}}{true}}
{
    The string ' -string$\sim$' ends with a tilde (\~{}). \footnote{This is a footnote}. \par
}{
    The string ' -string$\sim$' DOES NOT end with a tilde (\textasciitilde{}). \footnote{This is a footnote}. \par
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The \IfEndWith macro seems to correctly identify the tilde (~) at the end of the string '. -string~', but the \ifthenelse{\equal{\ifendSwith{ -string~}} macro does not.

Any suggestions or thoughts greatly appreciated.

For those that are wondering, "Why do they need to check for a tilde at the end of a string?", I need to use the non-breaking character as part of a longer text string, but need to know if and when the tilde character already exists at the end of the sub-string in question.

Thanks for reading.

**Update**:

Apologies for not being as explicit as I should have been with the original posting. Here is the original code that I was attempting to have test #1 for the last character as a tilde (~) (#2 can be any text):

```
\if \ifendswith{~}{#1}
    \myuline{\gls[hyper=true]{\trimend{#1}#2}}\index{#2!#1}%
\else
    \myuline{\gls[hyper=true]{#1 #2}}\index{#2!#1}%
\fi
```

When #1 = 'string~', `\ifendswith{~}{#1}` does **NOT** evaluate to .true. as I would have liked, and the \if \else \fi code does not work as hoped.

Again, apologies for the code that I should have included in my original posting.

Comment: almost all of this is a duplicate of your last question, which showed you that all your endswith tests will fail except testing for `~`, I would not expect a "trim spaces" function to remove `~` it is not a space. This seems to be an X-Y question, if you said more about your real case someone could suggest something. You can not use `\IfEndsWith in `\ifthenelse` as it has optional arguments and it uses xstring, both of which means it does not work by expansion.

Comment: I somewhat suspect trim@post@space is unexpandable, but not sure.

Comment: If `\ifthenelse{\equal{\ifendSwith{ -string~}}{true}}` worked it would be exactly the same as `\ifendSwith{ -string~}` so why would you ever need this???

Comment: @David Carlisle - Thank you for your comments. Apologies for not responding sooner. LaTeX is not my forte by any stretch and it can be overwhelming at times. (LaTeX is so powerful, I wish I had another lifetime to understand better how it all works!)

Comment: You have completly changed the question. `\if \ifendswith{..}` expands `\ifendswith` (which will produce arbibtrary internal nonsense), then test the first two non-expandable tokens for character quality, _every_ command will count as equal to every other command (and not equal to any letter) please check what `\if` does. You could ask a question about `\if` but it's not really _this_ question.

Answer (score 2):

This shows three versions of a string, ending no space, a `~` and a normal space.

First used as-is, then used after trimming any trailing space, and finally used after trimming then adding a `~` no breaking space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\sA{-string}
\newcommand\sB{-string~}
\newcommand\sC{-string }

\newcommand\trimsp{\ifhmode\unskip\unskip\unpenalty\fi}

\begin{document}

\sA!

\sB!

\sC!

\bigskip


\sA\trimsp!

\sB\trimsp!

\sC\trimsp!


\bigskip


\sA\trimsp~!

\sB\trimsp~!

\sC\trimsp~!

\end{document}
```

Comment: the master of spaces ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the master of never using a package with my name on.

Comment: @David Carlisle - Thank you for the code. I'm not looking to eliminate the tilde (~) at the end of the string as much as to test for the existence of the tilde at the end of a string so that my code \if \ifendswith{~}{#1} (See **Update**) will work as I'd hoped. Apologies if my original posting was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

No `xstring` command is expandable. So your `\equal{\ifendSwith{ -string~}}{true}` will always compare `true` with something completely different. And your definition with an optional argument makes things worse.

If you try full expansion with

```
\edef\test{\ifendSwith{ -string~}}
\show\test
```

you get

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
```

and if you go past errors you get

```
> \test=macro:
->\let \reserved@d =[\def \par .
```

which is definitely different from `true`.

You can remove a trailing `~` with the following code. The last token of the argument is compared with `\c_tilde_str` (as strings) and in this case only the tokens up to the last-but-one are delivered; otherwise the entire argument is delivered.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\removetie}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \c_tilde_str } { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
   {
    \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -2 }
   }
   {
    #1
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\removetie{string}X

\removetie{string~}X

\edef\test{\removetie{string~}}\texttt{\meaning\test}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your code! How can I adapt your code into a function to replace the \if \ifendswith{~}{#1} in my **Update:** above with something that will allow my \if \else \fi statement to work?

Comment: @RosesBouquet It's difficult to say without a full example including the definition of commands.